# spring boot ignore field dynamically jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot REST Web Services and Angular 5 as a frontend, well I have a model class for hibernating like this :

```
@Entity
public class Title {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private Date releaseDate;
        private Time runtime;
        private String storyline;
        private String picture;
        private String rated;
        private String type;
        private Double rating;
        private Integer numberOfVotes;
        private Timestamp inserted;
        private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
        private List<TitleCelebrity> titleCelebrities;
        private List<TitleMedia> titleMedia;

        // Basic getters and setter

        @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        @JoinTable(name = "title_genre", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "title_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id") })
        public Set<Genre> getGenres() {
            return genres;
        }

        public void setGenres(Set<Genre> genres) {
            this.genres = genres;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<TitleCelebrity> getTitleCelebrities() {
            return titleCelebrities;
        }

        public void setTitleCelebrities(List<TitleCelebrity> titleCelebrities) {
            this.titleCelebrities = titleCelebrities;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<TitleMedia> getTitleMedia() {
            return titleMedia;
        }

        public void setTitleMedia(List<TitleMedia> titleMedia) {
            this.titleMedia = titleMedia;
        }
    }
```

And here's my REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("titles")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
public class TitleController {

    private TitleService titleService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTitleService(TitleService titleService) {
        this.titleService = titleService;
    }

    // Api to get all the movies ordered by release date
    @GetMapping("movies")
    public List<Title> getAllMoviesOrderByReleaseDateDesc() {
        return this.titleService.findByTypeOrderByReleaseDateDesc("movie");
    }

    @GetMapping("movies/{id}")
    public Title findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return this.titleService.findById(id);
    }

}
```

What I want is when I make a request to the first method '/movies' i don't want the collection of Telemedia, but if I make a request to the second method '/movies/id' i want the collection of Telemedia.
of course, the annotation `@JsonIgnore` will ignore the collection whatever the request is.

Comment: Why not just set it to `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to create two models in this case; one to represent the first response and another to represent the second response.

You could also set the collection to `null` in your second request before sending it back.

You cannot accomplish this with `@JsonIgnore` alone as you cannot perform conditional logic in annotations.